# Variance of $\overline X = \frac{1}n \sum X_i$

Tags: statistics

I know that $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d., $E(X_i) = \mu$ and $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2$ and I also know that $Var(\overline X) = \sigma^2/n$ and how to prove that.
What I don't get is why we can't calculate $Var(\overline X) = Var(\frac{1}n \sum_i X_i) = Var(\frac{1}n nX_1) = Var(X_1) = \sigma^2$.
I know that this is a very silly question but I just don't see it.

Comment: Distribution of $\sum_i X_i$ is not the same as distribution of $nX$. Why would they have the same variance?

Comment: Oh I realized that I wrote $X$ not $X_1$ I edited that. I know I confuse distributions with normal variables but could you give me a refresher on why the distribution of $nX_1$ is different from $\sum_i X_i$ in this case even if $X_1,...,X_n$ is i.i.d. ?

Comment: $\sum_i X_i$ and $nX_i$ are not the same objects. The $X_i$ s are independent and identically *distributed*, not identical in value.

Comment: $X_i=X_1$ for all $i$ is almost the opposite of $X_i$'s being i.i.d.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks Golden_Ratio and Kavi Rama Murthy I know that I confuse distributions and variables, I had a little break from statistics and it shows

Comment: For $X_i$ iid, a key step would be $Var(\frac 1 n \sum_j X_i )= (1/n)^2Var(\sum_i X_i).$